Testing for joint spatial clustering across multiple variables
I have an analysis that I'm uncertain how to conduct. I have a GeoPandas dataframe that consists of a few hundred sample points (rows) and for each point I have counts of different variables. These are counts of jellyfish, phytoplankton type A,  phytoplankton type B, and  phytoplankton type C. This data was collected on a ship that was moving across the study area basically randomly. I want to test if certain phytoplankton groups are jointly clustered spatially with jellyfish. But I'm unsure how to actually approach this. Should I simply test if there is a correlation between the groups and the jellyfish? If high jellyfish counts are always associated with high phytoplankton A counts I could possibly claim they are jointly clustered? This approach seems to miss something about the spatial aspect but I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any advice?
My geodataframe
jellyfish_gdf
has columns
'Lat', 'Lon', 'jellyfish_density', 'phytoplankton_A_count', 'phytoplankton_B_count', 'phytoplankton_B_count', 'geometry', 'utc_dt'
And it is quite easy to test for a correlation:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,4))
ax.scatter(jellyfish_gdf['jellyfish density'], jellyfish_gdf['phytoplankton_A_count'])
ax.set_xlabel('jellyfish concentraion [count]')
ax.set_ylabel('phytoplankton A concentration [#/mL]')
plt.show()


but this seems to be missing something because viewed on a map they do appear to cluster spatially.
